# PrincipalOperationException when trying to connect to Active Directory in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, active-directory

Trying to connect to a Active Directory through PrincipalContext. I have seen the docs and all the ways it can be overloaded. No direction on when to use which arguments though.

Mine is set up as so:

```
    PrincipalContext pc = null;
    ContextOptions options = ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer | ContextOptions.SimpleBind;
    pc = new PrincipalContext( ContextType.Domain, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ActiveDirectoryIP"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DomainControllerValues"], options);
```

In my web.config I have the AcitiveDirectoryIP set up as "abc.com:3269" as this needs to be set up as an SSL connection. The DomainControllerValues are of this format: 'DC=us,DC=***,DC=com'.

The exception Im getting is:

```
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalOperationException: An operations error occurred.
 ---> System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException: An operations error occurred.

   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_SchemaEntry()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.IsContainer(DirectoryEntry de)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx..ctor(DirectoryEntry ctxBase, Boolean ownCtxBase, String username, String password, ContextOptions options)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.CreateContextFromDirectoryEntry(DirectoryEntry entry)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoLDAPDirectoryInit()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoLDAPDirectoryInit()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoDomainInit()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.Initialize()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.get_ConnectedServer()
```

Comment: Check the `InnerException`

Comment: It's possible that the SSL certificate used is not trusted on the computer you're running this from.